# How do I keep my result field blank until data in my formula is entered in excel?

Tags: excel, if-statement

Can someone help me fix this formula:

```
=IF(AND(B5="none",C5="none",D5="none"),"-","Input")
```

This is my current formula and it works the way I want it to work, but I want the cells in E5 to stay blank if there is nothing in the cells used in the formula.

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
=IF(COUNTA(B5:D5)<>3,"",IF(AND(B5="none",C5="none",D5="none"),"-","Input"))
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question, you want the word "Input" displayed in cell E5 unless the cells B5 thru D5 are empty. If the cells are empty, E5 should also be blank. Use the COUNTA(*range*) function to determine if any of the cells in the range are not blank.

```
=IF(COUNTA(B5:D5)>0,IF(AND(B5="none",C5="none",D5="none"),"-","Input"),"")
```

An optional enhancement is to add a trim function in case the user enters additional spaces around the word "none".

```
=IF(COUNTA(B5:D5)>0,IF(AND(TRIM(B5)="none",TRIM(C5)="none",TRIM(D5)="none"),"-","Input"),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it:

`=IF(SUMPRODUCT(INT(B5:D5={"","",""}))>0,"",IF(AND(B5="none",C5="none",D5="none"),"-","Input"))`

Personally I prefer this method because it's clearer to other users (and your future self) what you're trying to do.

Alternatively, you can do this:

`=IF(OR(B5:D5={"","",""}),"",IF(AND(B5:D5={"none","none","none"}),"-","Input"))`

This is even clearer, but in this case you'll have to array-enter the formula (`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`).

Answer (score 0):

Another way to accomplish this would be to forget about changing your formula at all and use conditional formatting instead.

Apply a new conditional formatting rule to cell `E5`. Format the cell so the text color is white. Enter the following truth test:

`=OR(B5="",C5="",D5="")`

See screenshots below.

Select cell `E5` and select `New Rule` from `Conditional Formatting` on the `Home` tab.

[image]

Select "Use a formula to determine..." and enter the truth test formula above in the blank.

[image]

Select format on the previous dialog box, and change the cell text color to white.

[image]

Now the cell will appear blank when one of the other cells are blank.